# PHP/MYSQL: ORDER BY ASC if Negative or DESC if Positive with AS clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So there is a multiplier that is randomly generated. It can be -1 or 1.

```
$query = "SELECT *, A * $MULTIPLIER1 + B * $MULTIPLIER2 + C * $MULTIPLIER3 AS totalnumber FROM data_table
ORDER BY totalscore DESC
LIMIT 4"
```

This code itself works. However, if there are TOO many negative multiplier the "totalnumber" becomes a negative number thus ruining the ORDER BY.

I need the "totalnumber" to reverse orders if the number is negative. And descend if the "totalnumber" is positive. Is that possible?

Basically if I have...

1. 20
2. 15
3. -5
4. -10

Then it becomes (the negative numbers can become abs(values))

1. 20
2. 15
3. 10
4. 5

or is it possible to ORDER BY totalnumber (100,-100, 99, -99, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with a two-part `order by`:

```
order by (totalnumber > 0) desc,
         abs(totalnumber) desc
```